# Visual Studio for Mac for Mobile Devices (Xamarin) - C# Automated Unit Testing

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.ios

It seems really bizarre that Visual Studio for Mac (the recently-renamed Xamarin Studio) doesn't support automated unit testing for their mobile device (Android/iOS) applications.  Actually, I guess it isn't that bizarre, they REALLY want you to pay for their cloud testing service.

How can I run my own automated unit tests, on my own machine?  Here's what I mean by that - I want to create an application that:

1. Contains C# files containing unit tests that require NO user interface
2. Can be invoked from my Jenkins or Hudson automated build server
3. Can run on either a physical iDevice attached to the build server, or the iPad simulator
4. Runs all unit tests, reports their pass/fail status back to the build server, and then exits, all without any human intervention.

It seems like I could do this on the simulator using

```
xcrun simctl spawn
```

and then either

1. Have my test app writes its output to its storage and figure out where on my Mac's hard disk the simulator storage lives, or
2. Have my test app send its output to the simulator's pasteboard and grab it using

   ```
   xcrun simctl pbpaste
   ```

But these both require that I find a way to write a C# app that runs on iOS, runs my tests, stores the output where the "real world" can find it, and then shuts down.

And I have to figure out how to copy all of the necessary EXEs and DLLs over to the simulated iPad?  Or have Visual Studio package it all into an actual Mac app?

Answer (score 1):

To run unit tests on an actual device you can use NUnit.Xamarin. This is a library that creates a Xamarin.Forms app that you can run on the real device, and this app will look for unit tests and run them:

https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin

You have to run this manually as an app and look at the results. If you want to automate that part then you can create a Xamarin UITest automated test to launch your app, let the tests run then download the results.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/

This is something we do using Jenkins as part of our standard mobile app pull requests. Jenkins runs a script that runs the UITest unit tests to launch the unit test app, wait for a result then grab the output and either pass or fail the UI test depending on the result of the screen output.

We just look for 'Test passed' or 'Test Failed', and if the test fails we manually run them to look for what went wrong, but you could expand on the UI test to download the results.

Comment: Can you maybe reference some links that explain what tools we can use to run the tests from the command line? Also how can we pull a xUnit .xml file that contains the test results from the emulator?